# dynatable.js vs dataTable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Between dynatable.js and datatable.js which plugin is preferrable? I have used an old version of datatable and I think it is a good one for interactive tables. Reading the dynatable official website documentation, this plugin seems to be better than datatable but I have not used it in order to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

I used datatables, old version and a new version, and i liked it very much.
I never used dynatable.js, but it seems that it doesn't have much traction (last commit was in September 2014) and 30k downloads (seems low).
Also datatables has a lot of nice plugins like col reorder, col vis, scroller and table tools.

If i would have the option to chose, i would go for datatables, cause it's seems to be the more reliable product.